# Putting a fragment into framelayout : fragment's listview is null

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment

I try to populate a activity with a fragment and the listview of the fragment is null when i try to load the fragment. I have tried to add a setContentView(R.layout.fragment) to activity but i have an error no view found.

Here is a part of my activity main code

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val fragmentCourant: Fragment = Fragment()
        val fm: FragmentManager = supportFragmentManager//supportFragmentManager//getSupportFragmentManager()//supportFragmentManager
        val transaction: FragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction()
       transaction.replace(R.id.FrameLayout,fragmentCourant)
        transaction.commit()
```

Here is a part of my fragment

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        val view=inflater?.inflate(R.layout.fragment,container,false)
        val button=view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
        var listView = view.findViewById<ListView>(R.id.listView)
        listView.adapter=CustomAdapter(DataClass(),this)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Use ‘FragmentContainerView’

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN)

        val fragmentCourant = Fragment()
        fragmentCourant.arguments = intent.extras

        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.FrameLayout, fragmentCourant)
            .commit()
    }
```